# Posfix pipe all incoming emails to PHP.... NO REWRITING

Tags: php, postfix

I'm trying to get Postfix to pipe ALL email coming in on a specific domain to a PHP script. So far I've been able to do this via a tutorial I found on the web and also editing the `/etc/postfix/virtual` file with something like what's below;

```
@domain.com root
```

The problem is that Postfix is re-writing the original recipient email address (for example **my_fake_email@domain.com**) to **root@domain.com** and the PHP script receiving the email does not get the original recipient (my_fake_email@domain.com). It is important that the PHP script sees my_fake_email@domain.com instead of root@domain.com.

Is it possible for Postfix to direct all incoming mail to the PHP script without modifying the address like in the example above?

Note: There can/will potentially be 10,000's of incoming email addresses.

Any ideas on how I can get Postfix to do what I want?

Comment: Got this working but haven't a clue how I did so. I will need to rebuild the server again in a couple of weeks time. Once I do I will post the steps here.

Answer (score 1):

You could set an additional header via Postfix:

create a `/etc/postfix/appendheader.regexp`:

```
/(.+)/ PREPEND X-Original-To: $1
```

in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

```
smtpd_data_restrictions = pcre:/etc/postfix/append_header.regexp
```

This will add an `X-Original-To:`-header with the original mail address before it's getting rewritten. Have your PHP-Script parse this header instead of the `To:`-Header.

Comment: Postfix _already does this_, which is the behavior he's complaining about.

Comment: Where exactly is he complaining about getting an `X-Original-To:`-header?

Comment: Unfortunately this cannot work because I want this file to later be indexed by a third party app. Letting Postfix rewrite the address will mean that the third party app will ultimately read the value in the "To" field as root@domain.com and index the document incorrectly.